# Java. I'm using three separate combo boxes with identical items. Changing the selection in one affects all three and I need to unlink them

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I'm using data from an array in a separate class to set the selected items available in a set of combo boxes. 3 of the boxes have identical data but the user needs to be able to have separate selections for each box. Both setting the selected item within the code and changing the selection within the GUI seems to affect all three boxes.

```
MainPage.editStudentGUI.getChoice1TeacherList().setSelectedItem(teachers[lessons[MainPage.loginID - 1].getChoice1() - 1].getSurname());       


MainPage.editStudentGUI.getChoice2TeacherList().setSelectedItem(teachers[lessons[MainPage.loginID - 1].getChoice2() - 1].getSurname());       


MainPage.editStudentGUI.getChoice3TeacherList().setSelectedItem(teachers[lessons[MainPage.loginID - 1].getChoice3() - 1].getSurname());
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwD77.jpg (I dont have enough reputation for images)
Its the three boxes in the bottom right

Comment: Feels like you have failed to leverage arrays/lists to their best advantage.  It's hard to see your problem from the code you've posted.  Got a screen shot you can post?  Seeing how the list values are modified would help.

Comment: https://imgur.com/bf2rfT3
Thats the generation of the string arrays that I'm using

Comment: Can you edit the image into your question?  I mean a UI screen shot, not the code.

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood, ill do that now

Comment: will have to see more code. where are u saving to this variable ... and the values of these variables teachers[lessons[MainPage.loginID - 1].getChoice1() - 1].getSurname() ... if possible put it in a public or private gitlab.com and share with  tgkprog unless its for a company/ proprietory code?

Comment: They're all stored in the same class and have been read in from a database. This is all stored locally, nothing is online. loginID is in a separate class obviously but it is a protected variable in the same package.

Comment: I figured it out, thanks for all your help. I was using the same model for all three boxes